# How to use data from ajax load function?

Tags: ajax, jquery

Let's say I have the following code below. Depending on which value they select from the dropdown, it displays checkboxes associated with the value. This part works just fine, except when I go submit the form, the data from the ajax call (`process.php`) isn't loaded. I dont see it in view source, therefore I'm not able to include them within `<form></form>`

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown').change( function() {
        $('#output').load('/process.php',{dropdown: $(this).val()});
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option value="QU">QU</option>
    <option value="QF">QF</option>
    <option value="QC">QC</option>
</select>

<div id="output"></div>
<button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

BTW, I've also tried the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown').live("change", function() {
        $('#output').load('/process.php',{dropdown: $(this).val()});
    });
});
```

***Snippet of process.php***

The results display just fine, except I can't use the checkbox values in the form submit.

```
foreach($new as $r) {
    $svn_tag = rtrim($r['current_tag'], '/');
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><label class='checkbox'><input name='tag[{$r['name']}]' type='checkbox' value='{$r['name']}'  /></label></td>";        
    echo "<td class='primary'>". ucfirst($r['name']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='primary'><input type='text' name='revision[{$r['name']}]' value='{$svn_tag}'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='docroot[{$r['name']}]' value='{$r['docroot']}'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Let's make this easier. I changed `process.php` to just display the following. Remember, it displays just fine, except it isn't included during the form submission.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tag" value="test">
```

I check the box, hit the Continue button and it fails. Meaning, the value of `tag` isn't passed to the next method. Basically if you view source, nothing is displayed within the `output` div.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code being returned by `process.php`?

Comment: Where is your #output element?  I assume it's just missing in your snippet but I've had worse d'oh moments

Comment: Added, i didn't include the method that processes the data, but the snippet shows you what it displays. It works, except I can't utilize the checkboxes during the form submit.

Comment: Are you trying to render table rows to a div?

Comment: Added ... process.php is basically loaded into that `output` div. Maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: No, does it matter how I'm displaying it? The issue is I can't use the values from the checkboxes. Forget how it's render, unless I'm missing the point?

Comment: @luckytaxi is the `#output` element inside the form ?

Comment: You should include the code in the process.php file that shows how it takes the `dropdown` argument and uses it in the return output.

Comment: DOH ... it's working now. The `<form>` tags were in the wrong place. Ugggggggh...